# Remove decimal from float object to plot

Tags: python, format, decimal, concatenation, truncate

I am trying to make a graph that has the CompanyName + Total Number of Calls as a label.

I am using bokeh with this command

```
p.text(xr, yr, df.CompanyName + df.Total, angle=label_angle,
text_font_size="9pt", text_align="center", text_baseline="middle")
```

but CompanyName is a str and Total is a float object so things are getting complicated. I fixed the `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects` and managed to graph it using

```
p.text(xr, yr, df.CompanyName + (map(str,df.Total)), angle=label_angle,
    text_font_size="9pt", text_align="center", text_baseline="middle")
```

However, this prints the CompanyName and a number with a decimal. I've tried all manner of cutting out this decimal, from the oft suggested:

```
"{:.0f}".format(df.Total)
```

which gives me this: `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`

What the heck, when I `print df.Total` I get `dtype: float64`
If I try `floor(df.Total)` I get `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>`
I am very confused. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Try converting it to an int first.

Comment: Something like `map(str, map(int, df.Total))`

Comment: Thanks @Brobin ! That worked. I had tried converting it to an int outside of that command but then it was still getting mad about types. Your method of converting it to an int inside map made it work.

Comment: Awesome, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the float to an int first and then a string. You need to use `map` because `df.Total` is an iterable. That's why `float(df.Total)` does not work.

```
map(str,map(int, df.Total))
```

Then you can concatenate it in your bokeh call.

```
p.text(xr, yr, df.CompanyName + map(str,map(int, df.Total)),
       angle=label_angle, text_font_size="9pt",
       text_align="center", text_baseline="middle")
```